# How do you filter your JSON data before it is send to your front end based on role in Express and MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, backend

I was searching online, but couldn't find any framework nor code that could help me.

So what I want to do is that whenever I send a response to my front-end, I want to filter my data based on the users his role.

**For example:**

**DB:**

```
 User: (name, it_skill, current_project, finished_projects [])
```

If I send a GET request and my role = admin, I want to get all the information about the user, but 
If my role = employee, I don't want to recieve finished_projects[].

I'm also searching for a DRY approach, at this moment I have the next code

```js
router.get('/user/:id', signedInCheck, hasRole('admin'), userController.getUserAsAdmin);

router.get('/user/:id', signedInCheck, hasRole('employee') userController.getUserAsEmployee);
```

And the only thing that different between getUserAsAdmin and getUserAsEmployee is the mongdo db code:

```
UserDB.findById(user_id)
```

vs

```
UserDB.findById(user_id, '-finished_projects')
```

But is would be much smoother if just before my response my JSON string that I send gets checked. 
because if I don't want to write 2 different kind of routes anytime I need another.

Is there some kind of a framework for? Or a design pattern to implement this kind of thing

Comment: Create one controller function like `userController.getUser` and inside this function you can add your roles conditions if its admin then return `userController.getUserAsAdmin` and its employee then return `userController.getUserAsEmployee`

Comment: @turivishal I understand your awnser, but then I need to change everything when I add a 3rd role. I would be nice if its possible to change my outgoing response based on a role.

Comment: Check my answer, if its helpful.

Comment: keep it simple, go with 2 routes, dont stack everything up in 1 route

Answer (score 0):

**UserController:** there are functions for retrieving data for user, like:

```
// ADMIN FUNCTION
function getUserAsAdmin(){  
    // querying form db or retrieving data from model
    // UserDB.findById(user_id) 
    // return your response;
}
```

```
// EMPLOYEE FUNCTION
function getUserAsEmployee(){  
    // querying form db or retrieving data from model
    // UserDB.findById(user_id, '-finished_projects')
    // return your response;
}
```

Just create a new function in this controller like below:

```
// ADMIN OR EMPLOYEE FUNCTION
function getUser(){

    if ( hasRole('admin') ) {
        // call admin function
        getUserAsAdmin();
    }
    else if ( hasRole('employee') ) {
        // call employee function
        getUserAsEmployee();
    }

}
```

And your single route will be like:

```
router.get('/user/:id', signedInCheck, userController.getUser);
```

If you have more then 2 roles or you want to check both roles in middleware in single function then you have to modify `hasRole()` role checker function to check both from array, **ex: role must be one from array**

```
router.get('/user/:id', signedInCheck, hasRole(['admin', 'employee']) userController.getUser);
```

Hope this will help.